# Subsets of list nat in coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I defined a recursive function for all subsets of nat_list in coq as

```
Fixpoint subsets (a: list nat) : (list (list nat)) :=
 match a with
  |[] => [[]]
  |h::t => subsets t ++ map (app [h]) (subsets t)
end.
```

I am trying to prove that

```
forall (a:list nat), In [] (subsets a).
```

I tried to induct on a. The base-case was straight forward. However in the induction case i tried to use the in-built theorem `in_app_or`.

```
Unable to unify "In ?M1396 ?M1394 \/ In ?M1396 ?M1395" with
"(fix In (a : list nat) (l : list (list nat)) {struct l} : Prop := 

match l with
| [] => False
| b :: m => b = a \/ In a m     
end)                                                         
[] (subsets t ++ map (fun m : list nat => h :: m) (subsets t))".
```

How do I prove such a theorem or get around such an issue?

Comment: Note about your naming, your function doesn't return "a subset" in the sense of a list of lists not having the same properties as a set of lists. In particular, do the lists `[a; b]` and `[b; a]` represent the same set? Think about it!

Comment: For what it's worth, in this case, "`induction l; simpl; intuition.`" is also a valid proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `in_app_or` is that is has the following type:

```
forall (A : Type) (l m : list A) (a : A),
  In a (l ++ m) -> In a l \/ In a m
```

and application of lemmas to the goal works "backwards": Coq matches the consequent `B` of the implication `A -> B` with the goal, and if they can be unified, you are left with a new goal: you need to prove a (stronger) statement `A`. And in your case the `A` and `B` are in the wrong order (swapped), so you need to apply `in_or_app` instead:

```
in_or_app : forall (A : Type) (l m : list A) (a : A),
  In a l \/ In a m -> In a (l ++ m)
```

This is how your goal can be proved using `in_or_app`:

```
Goal forall (a:list nat), In [] (subsets a).
  intros.
  induction a; simpl; auto.
  apply in_or_app; auto.
Qed.
```